Duplicate file upload get fail in same SFTP Session
I have recently migrated one of Spring Boot SFTP service to 3.3.2 from 2.7.18. The app has ability to upload the file. The application was able to upload duplicate files in same session to same location, but in new version the app is failing to upload same file for 2nd attempt in same session. The major difference is, spring-integration-sftp is using Apache Mina SSHD library to make SFTP operations. The 1st attempt of file upload works fine. On the second attempt of file upload app faces error.
Open SFTP Session.
Attempt1 : Upload test.txt -> works fine.
Attempt 2 : Re Upload test.txt -> Upload fails. (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED): file is not partially uploaded
The below class create a SFTP Session:
@Configuration
public class SftpConnectionFactory {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SftpConnectionFactory.class);
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, SessionFactory> factoryMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    ConcurrentHashMap<String, SftpClient> sftpClientMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Autowired
    private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public DelegatingSessionFactory dsf() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        DelegatingSessionFactory dsf = new DelegatingSessionFactory(sftpSessionFactoryLocator());
        return dsf;
    }


    public DefaultSessionFactoryLocator sftpSessionFactoryLocator() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        DefaultSessionFactoryLocator fl = new DefaultSessionFactoryLocator(factoryMap);
        return fl;
    }

    public void validateAndCreateConnection(SftpDetails details) {
        try {
            if (!factoryMap.containsKey(details.getKey())) {
                //synchronized block to avoid multiple request to create connection at a time.
                synchronized (this) {
                    if (!factoryMap.containsKey(details.getKey())) {
                        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
                        logger.info("Creating sftp connection for user " + details.getUserName() + " for remote destination " + details.getRemoteDestination());
                        factory.setHost(details.getHostName());
                        factory.setPort(details.getPort());
                        factory.setUser(details.getUserName());
                        if (details.getPrivateKey() != null) {
                            factory.setPrivateKey(new ByteArrayResource(details.getPrivateKey().getBytes()));
                            factory.setPrivateKeyPassphrase(details.getKeyPassphrase());
                        } else {
                            factory.setPassword(details.getPassword());
                        }

                        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
                        //factory.setSessionConfig(buildSessionProperties());
                        ///create the factory locator
                        factoryMap.put(details.getKey(), factory);

                    } else {
                        logger.info("Connection already exist for user " + details.getUserName() + " for remote destination " + details.getRemoteDestination());
                    }
                }

            } else {
                logger.info("Connection already exist for user " + details.getUserName() + " for remote destination " + details.getRemoteDestination());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Failed to create and store SFTP connection. : "+e.getMessage());
            throw new SftpException(e.getMessage(), "Failed to create and store SFTP connection. : "+e.getMessage());
        }

    }

}

The below class perform the upload activity.
@Service
public class UploadServiceImpl implements UploadService {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UploadServiceImpl.class);
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    @Autowired
    private SftpConnectionFactory factory;

    private final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(SftpServiceConstant.DATE_FORMAT);

    private StringBuffer load(SftpDetails details, int retryCount){
        StringBuffer message = new StringBuffer();
        factory.validateAndCreateConnection(details);

        //SFTP the files for remote destination
        SftpSession session = null;

        try(FileInputStream fIS = new FileInputStream(details.getTempSourceFilePath())) {
            session = (SftpSession) factory.dsf().getFactoryLocator().getSessionFactory(details.getKey()).getSession();
            //This block will be enabled to create the daily folders as per job configuration
            String fileName ="";
            String destPath = details.getRemoteDestination();

            String remoteHomeDir = session.getClientInstance().canonicalPath(SftpServiceConstant.CURRENT_DIR);
            if(destPath.startsWith(SftpServiceConstant.DOUBLE_FORWARD_SLASH)) {
                destPath = destPath.substring(1);
            }else if(destPath.startsWith(SftpServiceConstant.FILE_SEPERATOR) && !SftpServiceConstant.FILE_SEPERATOR.equals(remoteHomeDir)){
                destPath = remoteHomeDir+destPath;
            }

            String startTime=sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
            logger.info("The file upload started. :"+destPath+" StartTime: "+startTime);
            session.write(fIS, destPath ); //working fine --+ File.separator + file.getName()
            logger.info("The file upload completed.:"+destPath+" StartTime: "+startTime+" EndTime: "+sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

            message.append(MessageFormat.format(env.getProperty("sftp.success.msg"), fileName,details.getRemoteDestination())).append("\n");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("File Upload Failed : "+e.getMessage(),e);
            throw new SftpException(e.getMessage(), "Failed to upload remote file : "+ExceptionUtils.getRootCause(e));
        }

        return message;
    }
}

Error faced :

ERROR c.d.s.e.CustomExceptionHandler - Sftp Exception [file is not partially uploaded]
WARN  o.s.w.s.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [com.service.exception.SftpException: Failed to upload remote file : SFTP error (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED): file is not partially uploaded]

